# WooCommerce auto restore stock on order cancel

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payu

I'm looking for a solution to automatically restore stock when order is canceled. I'm using PayU gateway on my client's site and it works by setting all orders on hold when waiting for payment and cancels them after 24 hours if there's no valid payment made. However, this means that WooCommerce built-in mechanism for freezing stock and then restocking after given time doesn't work (as the payment gateway sets the status to on hold).

There was a plugin called WooCommerce Auto Restore Stock by Gerhard Potgieter but it's an oldie and I was unable to find a similar solution in WordPress plugin repository or on Codecanyon.

Perhaps someone stumbled upon a solution to auto restore stock for cancelled orders that works with WC 3.0+?

Answer (score 2):

According to woocommerce github issue [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/3712), they say that (24 hours hold stock & cancel without restock) is correct behavior. Orders can be cancelled for a variety of reasons - incorrect stock levels, faulty products, user choice etc etc therefore the re-increment of stock should be an entirely (manual) admin decision.

So, i try to override the function in my child theme`s functions.php and it works!

Here's the code :

```
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders', 'wc_cancel_unpaid_orders' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders', 'override_cancel_unpaid_orders' );

function override_cancel_unpaid_orders() {
    $held_duration = get_option( 'woocommerce_hold_stock_minutes' );

    if ( $held_duration < 1 || 'yes' !== get_option( 'woocommerce_manage_stock' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $data_store    = WC_Data_Store::load( 'order' );
    $unpaid_orders = $data_store->get_unpaid_orders( strtotime( '-' . absint( $held_duration ) . ' MINUTES', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );

    if ( $unpaid_orders ) {
        foreach ( $unpaid_orders as $unpaid_order ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $unpaid_order );

            if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_order', 'checkout' === $order->get_created_via(), $order ) ) {
                //Cancel Order
                $order->update_status( 'cancelled', __( 'Unpaid order cancelled - time limit reached.', 'woocommerce' ) );

                //Restock
                foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
                    // Get an instance of corresponding the WC_Product object
                    $product = $item->get_product();
                    $qty = $item->get_quantity(); // Get the item quantity
                    wc_update_product_stock($product, $qty, 'increase');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders' );
    wp_schedule_single_event( time() + ( absint( $held_duration ) * 60 ), 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders' );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63236150/2195238